# JqGrid Toolbar searching -set searchdata in field instead of post data directly

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to change the default search behavoir of the Filter Toolbar. The [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config) states:

> When the search is performed the postData array is filled with the needed data for the search.

So if you have a grid with an id and name column and you filter with those to columns, you get a query string that looks something like this:

```
?_search=true&nd=1323976178454&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc&id=11&name=jr
```

What I want is something like this

```
?_search=true&nd=1323976178454&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc&search[id]=11&search[name]=jr
```

How can this be accomplished?

## Edit:

I figured out that if i define my colModel like this:

```
{"name":"search[ID]","label":"id","jsonmap":"ID"}
```

It does what I want, but this seems hackish. Any better solutions?

Here is the js for my grid:

```
$("#contactsGrid").jqGrid({
    "url":"\/contacts",
    "datatype":"json", ,
    "viewrecords":true,
    "jsonReader":{
        "root":"items",
        "page":"page",
        "total":"total",
        "records":"records",
        "repeatitems":false,
        "id":0
    },
    "colModel":[
        {"name":"ID","label":"id","jsonmap":"ID","searchoptions":[],
            "formatter":"showlink","formatoptions":{"baseLinkUrl":"\/contacts"}},
        {"name":"Name","label":"Name","jsonmap":"Name"}
    ],
    "colNames":["id","name"],
    "pager":"contactsGrid-pager"
}).navGrid("#contactsGrid-pager",
    {"edit":false,"add":false,"del":false,"view":false});

$("#contactsGrid").filterToolbar({"autosearch":true});
```

Comment: There are many ways to solve your problem, but it's difficult to answer you because you don't posted the grid definition which you use. The searching field names are mostly the same as the names used in the sorting. Do you want to have `search[ID]` used as the value of `sidx`?

Comment: @Oleg i will be posting the code shortly. That is a good point, no I would still want just ID to be the value of sidx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringResult:true` to get results back in a more structured way.

```
$("#contactsGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true, autosearch:true});
```

Output:

```
_search: true
filters: {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"name","op":"bw","data":"jr"}]}
nd: 1323990002421
page: 1
rows: 10
sidx: date_won
sord: desc
```

You can then GET the "filters" array and do what you need with that.

[Read more about stringResult](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching&s%5B%5D=stringresult)

Also, I find it easier to just use the `loadonce: true` option so I don't have to handle the search query at all. Not as customizable but way easier.

[Read more about loadonce](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions&s%5B%5D=loadonce)